# border issue with button css on ionic (html app)

Tags: html, css, button, ionic-framework, border

[image: error]

I don't how to take off this "border" from my button. Already tryied a lot.
anyone have an ideia?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Background Images</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content class="card-background-page">
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-card>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          Laboratorio
        <ion-icon name="medkit"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-card>
        <button ion-button icon-right>
    Clinicas
    <ion-icon name="pulse"></ion-icon>
  </button>


      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-card>
        <button ion-button icon-left>
    <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
    Pele
  </button>

      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-card>
        <button ion-button icon-right>
  Odontologia
  <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
</button>


      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>

CSS :
.card-background-page {

  ion-card {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .card-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
  }

  .card-subtitle {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
  }

}

#button
{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: can you please copy/paste your code and don't use screenshoot. If possible give us the final HTML/CSS code and not the ionic one so we can check the css applied to the element

Comment: post an answer! tks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the **ion-card** tag and try without. I think this tag is adding the border.